# I got exception when try to read data from database with the help of OleDb

Tags: c#, oledbdatareader, oledbexception

Hello I am trying to use OleDb to connect database but when i want to read data from there and use Read() command after that

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", TextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", TextBox2.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read()) 
{                      
    string istifadeciAd = (string)rdr.GetString(1);
    string istifadeciParol = (string)rdr.GetString(2);
}
```

in String istifadeciAd and istifadeciParol i got error for GetString because of IndexoutofRange. But don't we need to call GetString with column index?

Comment: show the select statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to have more than 2 select columns in your select statement to get `rdr.GetString(2)`

something like below

`select id, istifadeciAd, istifadeciParol from Table1 where name =? and password =?`

**note that index is zero-based**

So if you only select `istifadeciAd, istifadeciParol` columns you need to read it as

```
string istifadeciAd = rdr.GetString(0);
string istifadeciParol = rdr.GetString(1);
```

And you don't need to cast the result to `string`, because it is returning `string`

I think you need to change the parameters adding code as well,

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text);
```